# Newton's method, find the initial value which will produce a periodic cycle when we start the iteration from this value.

Tags: functions

Consider applying Newton’s method to find the solution $x = 0$ of $\sin x = 0$. We know
the iteration will converge for initial guess $x_0$ close enough to 0, say $x_0 ∈ (−s, s).$

> (a) Find the largest possible value of $s$: that is, the largest $s$ for which Newton’s method
>   will converge to $0$ for any $x_0 ∈ (−s, s)$.

Answer (score 0):

The immediate basin of attraction for a root of $f(x)$ in Newton's method, if bounded, has a boundary that forms a $2$-cycle.  Thus, with $N(x) = x - \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$, that basin must be $(a,b)$ where $N(a) = b$ and $N(b)=a$.  By symmetry we expect $b = -a$, so
$a - \tan(a) = -a$, i.e. $\tan(a) = 2a$.  Solving this numerically, we have $a \approx -1.165561185$ and
$b \approx 1.165561185$.